# Performative verbs - speech act

Tags: english, pragmatics, speech-acts

The sentence: "I order you to do X". order is a performative verb, it is a speech act which has the illocutionary force is an order.
The sentence: "I inspire you to do X". Although is also looks like a performative verb, it does not seem to work as a speech act.
Any thoughts/ideas?
Many thanks

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: I suggest reading the entirety of *How to Do Things with Words* by Austin for the argument on why every utterance must be performative in all cases. I don’t know why people seem to be so hung up on the constative/performative distinction he proposes on the first half of the book, and obscure that the author himself deconstructs the distinction on the second half of the book.

Comment: Hi! have read the lectures, and Searles as well. I am only getting a sense that both, even though syntactically identical, both with performative verbs are both the same.

Comment: The sentence with _inspire_ reminds me of Marie Kondo; since I don't become inspired by virtue of reading (or hearing) your _inspiration_ sentence, it was not performative.  Performative predicates are social causatives. That's why they were such a natural frame for abstract syntax.

Comment: this question is too broad to possibly answer, as it stands. Please provide us with some more specific questions if you want us to provide answers

Comment: Hi. This is pretty much all I have. No additional context except the comparison with another sentence with the same syntactic structure. I guess trying to work out is Inspire is a performative verb and the sentence an illocutionary act (commissive/directive/other) or if this is just a constative.